# How can I mount a television with wiring in the wall behind?

Tags: studs

My husband and I are mounting a tv. The stud finder shows some type of electrical wires by the stud we need to drill into. How can we safely drill into this stud without nicking any wires? Or should we just avoid the area in general?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be absolutely sure is to cut an access hole and get a visual on it. If you hit a wire, it will need to be opened up anyway. If you have access to a small inspection camera, you could get away with drilling a much smaller hole.

Answer (score 0):

Standard advice is that you can mount to any stud if you stay inside about 1-1/4" of depth. If there are wires passing through the stud they should be centered, which keeps them out of harm's way, or protected by a steel plate.

Comment: "SHould be"   vs.   some previous genius's shortcuts   leads to sadness. Don't take anything for granted.

Comment: Hogwash. I've been mounting all manner of things to walls for decades. The work you'd create cutting holes to "be sure" far outweighs the risk of actually _damaging_ your wiring with this approach.

Comment: Gotta go with isherwood on this.

Answer (score -2):

It's always better to drill into a stud without any wires in the immediate area. If you can move over another 16" to the next stud. Or use one of the many reliable heavy duty hollow wall anchors for one anchor point and use a non-wired stud for the other you should be alright. There are hollow wall anchors that will support 75 lbs and up.  In other words, generally, all of the anchors for a wall mounted tv do not have to necessarily be in studs.

However, if that won't work for you you can drill into the wired stud with caution. Sometimes wiring will be stapled to the side of the stud **(However, see my comment below on wiring that runs through studs)**. With the stud finder you should be able to identify the side of the stud that the wire is on.  So when going into the stud you will want to make sure you hit center and not the edge so it's good to invest in a reliable stud finder. A single stud will be 1.5 inches wide. As long as you're careful in identifying the stud edges you should be okay.

Importantly, you'll want to turn off the power to the house before you drill.

***Bad oops on my part. I rushed this answer and neglected to address wires running horizontally through studs in walls. They are not always shielded by metal plates on the face of the stud and this area should be avoided. If you have to drill into the stud be sure to go at least six inches above or below the wire pass-through. Current must be off when drilling near any concealed wiring. Thanks to all of you astute StackExchangers for correcting me on this. ***

Comment: This answer could be wrong in many ways. Electrical wires very often pass through holes drilled into the studs.  To say that the wires are always just stapled to the sides of the stud is just plain not true. This is what earns the -1 vote.

Comment: if you can determine that the wires are continuously on a single side of the stud, then the stud can be drilled without risk.  else you risk hitting the wire if it crosses through the stud.

Comment: Mea culpa - You both are right! I knew that but rushed my answer. With wires running horizontally through studs in a wall it's best to only drill into the stud no closer than 6 inches above or below the pass-through.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. Didn't know that. But the main thing is to get the answer correct!

Comment: Edit your answer and correct it. You might get some of those "-"'s removed.